# How to wait for base class Resolver to complete before derived class Resolver executes?

Tags: angular, typescript

Many of my resolvers (@angular/router Resolve) need to query the same data before performing their route-specific query.  I'd like to use a resolver base class that resolves the initial data before resolve() in the derived class is executed.

*The base class:*

```
export class MyBaseResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
      
        myBaseProperty: string;

        constructor(service: MyService) {}
        
        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): string {
    
            this.service.getData()
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    this.myBaseProperty = data;
            });
        
        }
}
```

*The derived class:*

```
export class MyDerivedResolver implements Resolve<Observable<Thing>> extends MyResolverParent {

        constructor(public service: MyService) {
            super(service);
        }
        
        // How to make this wait for MyBaseResolver.resolve() to complete 
        // so "myBaseProperty" is available?
        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Thing> {
    
            return this.service.getOtherData(myBaseProperty);
        
        }
}
```

How can I get `MyDerivedResolver` to wait for `MyBaseResolver.resolve()` to complete so `myBaseProperty` is available and valid?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Resolver, but you **cannot** return synchronous data (`data` here) from an asynchronous call (`this.service.getData()` here).

Comment: @MichaelD yep you're correct, that's a mistake in the example I created and I didn't notice it before posting.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class MyDerivedResolver implements Resolve<Observable<Thing>> extends MyResolverParent {

        constructor(public service: MyService) {
            super(service);
        }
        
        // How to make this wait for MyBaseResolver.resolve() to complete 
        // so "myBaseProperty" is available?
        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Thing> {
            
            return super.resolve(route, state).pipe(mergeMap(()=>this.service.getOtherData(myBaseProperty)));
        
        }
}
```

but honestly, I don't get it why do you want resolve  `this.service.getData()` from base class.

Comment: Good suggestion, I will give it a try.    The reason I'd like to do this is all of my resolver classes require the same information (identifiers) before being able to request their own data.  Instead of repeating the same request in every resolver class, I'd like to encapsulate that code in a base class so resolvers only need to inherit from it.  Hopefully that explains it.   Based on the suggested solutions, the base class doesn't even need to implement the `Resolve` interface, which actually makes it even simpler.

Comment: Exactly. It's need to change `const data = await this.service.getData().toPromise();` to `const data = this.service.getData();` in your base class as well

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but this is the approach I'd take

```
export class MyBaseResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
      
        myBaseProperty: string;

        constructor(service: MyService) {}
        
        async resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): string {
    
            const data = await this.service.getData().toPromise();
            this.myBaseProperty = data;
            return data;
        
        }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll give that a try.   I don't know if Typescript will allow the `Resolve` interface method `resolve()` to be implemented as async, but it's easy enough to try.